# Change Data base on selected

Tags: html, jquery, css

Please see code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spl-comp-select").on("click", function(){
   $(".spl-comp-select").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.spl-company-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  width: 660px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: .12s scale-animate ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.spl-company-select-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  /*gap: 10px;*/
}

.spl-comp-select {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
 /* width: 33.33%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spl-comp-select.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #b369ff 30%, #9d5cff 70%);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.comp-icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #9d5cff30;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../media/icons/company-icon-44x44-gray.png);
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-icon {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/company-icon-44x44-white.png);
  background-color: #9d5dfc;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.spl-company-txt {
  font-size: 1.50em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #a86ce4;
}

.comp-name {
  font-size: 1.04em;
  color: #404e60;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-name {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-abbr {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.comp-abbr {
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #404e60;
}

.spl-action-btn {
  border: 1px solid #9e5cff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #9e5cff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 180px;
  min-width: 180px;
  max-width: 180px;
}


.spl-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.spl-action-btn.spl-back {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.spl-action-btn.spl-change {
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #7830c1 30%, #a264ff 70%);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pnlCompany-c">
  <div class="spl-company-box">
    <div class="spl-company-txt">Select Company Type</div>
    <div class="spl-company-select-box">
      <div class="spl-comp-select active">
        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 1</div>
        <div class="comp-abbr">ST1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="spl-comp-select">
        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 2</div>
        <div class="comp-abbr">ST2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="spl-comp-select">
        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 3</div>
        <div class="comp-abbr">ST3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spl-btn">
      <div class="spl-action-btn spl-back pnl-h-close">Back</div>
      <div class="spl-action-btn spl-change">Change Company</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="abbr-data">test</div>
```

Hi can anyone help me with this problem, my Goal is when I selected a company type and click the change company button. The `abbr-data` text should update base on `.comp-abbr data`

> Form Example
>
> I've selected Sample Text 2 ST2
>
> The Data should be updated to ST2. <"div"> class="abbr-data">ST2< "div" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please try this ?

```
  $('.spl-change').on('click',function(){
      var abbr = $('.active').find('.comp-abbr').html();
      $('.abbr-data').html(abbr);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @mmantach looking into it know

Answer (score 1):

In plain JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spl-comp-select").on("click", function(){
   $(".spl-comp-select").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});

const res = document.querySelector('.abbr-data')
const sel = document.querySelectorAll('.spl-comp-select')
const selBtn = document.querySelector('.spl-change')
let selected = ''
sel.forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const text = s.querySelector('.comp-abbr')
    selected = text.innerHTML
  })
})
selBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  res.innerHTML = selected
})
```

```css
.spl-company-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    width: 660px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: .12s scale-animate ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.spl-company-select-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    /*gap: 10px;*/
}

.spl-comp-select {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 15px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
   /* width: 33.33%;
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}

.spl-comp-select.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #b369ff 30%, #9d5cff 70%);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.comp-icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border: 2px solid #9d5cff30;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(../media/icons/company-icon-44x44-gray.png);
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-icon {
    background-image: url(../media/icons/company-icon-44x44-white.png);
    background-color: #9d5dfc;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.spl-company-txt {
    font-size: 1.50em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #a86ce4;
}

.comp-name {
    font-size: 1.04em;
    color: #404e60;
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-name {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.spl-comp-select.active .comp-abbr {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.comp-abbr {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #404e60;
}

.spl-action-btn {
    border: 1px solid #9e5cff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #9e5cff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 180px;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
}


.spl-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.spl-action-btn.spl-back {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.spl-action-btn.spl-change {
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #7830c1 30%, #a264ff 70%);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pnlCompany-c">
            <div class="spl-company-box">
                <div class="spl-company-txt">Select Company Type</div>
                <div class="spl-company-select-box">
                    <div class="spl-comp-select active">
                        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
                        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 1</div>
                        <div class="comp-abbr">ST1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spl-comp-select">
                        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
                        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 2</div>
                        <div class="comp-abbr">ST2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spl-comp-select">
                        <div class="comp-icon"></div>
                        <div class="comp-name">Sample Text 3</div>
                        <div class="comp-abbr">ST3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spl-btn">
                    <div class="spl-action-btn spl-back pnl-h-close">Back</div>
                    <div class="spl-action-btn spl-change">Change Company</div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>


<div class="abbr-data">test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Nikola Pavicevic looking into it know